# Unable to right-align input-group-text contents in form input field using Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am creating a form with multiple input elements using Bootstrap 5. A few of them will have input group text defined. I want the grey area displaying the input group text to be the same width for all fields, so I have defined that exact width using CSS (shown below using a style element for simplification).

The length of the input group text will be different of course among the fields, meaning some will have more empty space than others. I am attempting to right-align the text to make it look nicer on-screen. So far I have been unable to do so. Here is my goal visualized:

[image]

I have tried everything I could find, spent several hours reading over documentation and resolutions to similar alignment issues, and attempted to make this work, but so far have only met failure.

How can I make the input group text "Person" right align within the grey area? Is there a more appropriate way to define a uniform (but specific) width to the grey area?

```
<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-text" style="width: 200px;">Person</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/text/#text-alignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Bootstrap class `justify-content-end` on the `<input>`.

See the snippet below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <span class="input-group-text justify-content-end" style="width: 200px;">Person</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would swear that I had tried absolutely everything, yet here we are with the solution. I can't thank you enough for pointing out this class. There are so many alignment options, perhaps I had tried this but with other conflicting classes specified? In any case thank you so much!

Comment: @bodylice Hm, it's hard to say, but it can happen that you mix different Bootstrap classes that are conflicting or you set `justify-content-end` on the wrong element. You're welcome. :)